# CSS Select ListView by id

Tags: sharepoint-designer, css, aspx

I started with a blank ASPX page and added two list views to it. I am using CSS to modify some of the styles on the page, and I have been relatively successful; however, I am now trying to change the "ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell" class for only the first listview. So naturally I was trying to do

```
#id .ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell
```

However the ID of the listview table is: "{39F86178-3D5B-4272-B9AD-472E456467D3}-{G_326F2ECF_0DEB_4582_8F94_3BBEEE0327E1}" and it doesn't look like I am able to use that as a valid ID selector.

I.E.

```
#{39F86178-3D5B-4272-B9AD-472E456467D3}-{G_326F2ECF_0DEB_4582_8F94_3BBEEE0327E1} .ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell {
}
```

Does not work. What should I do to modify the .ms-vb2 ms-vb-lastCell class on only the first listview?

Comment: Could you use something like `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` to target the first list view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, unless that's a typo, it looks like you are missing a period between your class selectors, so it should be:

```
#id .ms-vb2.ms-vb-lastCell
```

But if the ID still isn't working, taking a quick look at a list view web part (in SP 2013, might be different in 2010, not sure what you are working in), it looks like the table has an attribute `summary` whose value is the list name.

So you could do something like

```
table[summary='My List Name'] .ms-vb2.ms-vb-lastCell
```

Comment: yep summary was available as an attribute in the tag which seems to be better, and you are right, I was missing the extra period as well.